# Javascript Highscore Not Working

Tags: javascript, variables

I am making a game using javascript and html. I would like to set up a highscore feature. `x` is the name of the current score you have. In the below code the `header` says "highscore" but it should say a number after I have finished playing the game.

```
<h2 id="highscore">Highscore</h2>

function highscorefunction() {
var highscore = localStorage.getItem("highscore");
if(highscore !== null){
   if (x > highscore) {
     localStorage.setItem("highscore", x );
     document.getElementById("highscore").textContent = highscore ;
   }
}else{
  localStorage.setItem("highscore", x );
  document.getElementById("highscore").textContent = highscore ;
}
}
```

Note: The below code says [object HTMLHeadingElement] rather then "highscore"

```
function highscorefunction() {
var highscore = localStorage.getItem("highscore");
if(highscore !== null){
   if (x > highscore) {
     localStorage.setItem("highscore", x );
  }
}else{
  localStorage.setItem("highscore", x );
}
}
document.getElementById("highscore").textContent = highscore ;
```

Can someone please show me where I went wrong

Comment: Where is `x` meant to magically come from?

Comment: *"x is the name of the current score you have."*, please show us how you got that value. Ensure that it's what you think it is and not an HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is just a number ensure that you define `highscore` outside the function `highscorefunction`, your browser is interpreting the global variable `highscore` as a reference to that HTML element by it's **id**.

```
function highscorefunction() {
    // Local variable "highscore"
    var highscore = localStorage.getItem("highscore");
    ...
}
// global variable "highscore", referring the HTML with the id of "highscore"
document.getElementById("highscore").textContent = highscore ;
```

So define `highscore` outside the function so it's not using the HTML element:

```
var highscore = localStorage.getItem("highscore");
function highscorefunction() {
    ...
}
document.getElementById("highscore").textContent = highscore ;
```

Comment: Do I do that line instead of localStorage.setItem("highscore", x );
  } or underneath  it

Comment: @987654321 You would do something along the lines of `localStorage.setItem("highscore", x.innerHTML );`.

Comment: x is a javascript variable not from HTML

Comment: x is defined :  x = 0;

Comment: @987654321 Oh I see the problem in the second snippet of code (I didn't notice there was a difference). In the second snippet the global variable `highscore` is referring to your HTML id element. It's only defined inside your function.

Comment: Please can you fill in the ... I am confused about what needs to go inside

Comment: @987654321 `...` just stands for the rest of the code you have.